# php imap_body - what email-Format is this and how do I decode it?

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm using the imap plugin for php5 and try to get the content of the e-mails of the connected account.
I use imap_open() to open a connnection and use the following function to get the emails.

```
function inbox() {
    $this->msg_count = imap_num_msg($this->conn);
    $in = array();
    for($i = 1; $i <= $this->msg_count; $i++) {
        $in[] = array(
            'index'     => $i,
            'header'    => imap_headerinfo($this->conn, $i),
            'body'      => imap_body($this->conn, $i),
            'structure' => imap_fetchstructure($this->conn, $i)
        );
    }

    $this->inbox = $in;
}
```

**However, if I try to get the body of my mails, it looks something like this:**

--089e01493f60f29e8205207968a6 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Palim Palim --089e01493f60f29e8205207968a6 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Palim Palim
--089e01493f60f29e8205207968a6--

**Or starts like this:**

AW: Design? ^^'
This is a multi-part message in MIME format. ------_=_NextPart_001_01D0EEEF.3B148526 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----_=_NextPart_002_01D0EEEF.3B148526" ------*=*

What do I have to do and how do I have to decode this, to get just the text in an html or plain-text format?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use imap_fetchbody()

`````
    $this->msg_count = imap_num_msg($this->conn);
    $in = array();
    for($i = 1; $i <= $this->msg_count; $i++) {
        $in[] = array(
            'index'     => $i,
            'header'    => imap_headerinfo($this->conn, $i),
            'body'      => imap_fetchbody($this->conn, $i, 2),
            'structure' => imap_fetchstructure($this->conn, $i)
        );
    }

    $this->inbox = $in;
} ````
`````